# Am I overthinking a probability question?

Tags: probability

Last year in my notes, I offered my class the following problem.

Four students, Al, Bo, Chip and Dale, must be seated in the front four pairs of desks in a room of 17 pairs of desks (34 desks in all), but they cannot sit together. Find the probability that this arrangement will occur.

With the assumption that the process is random, the answer I wrote down for myself is $\frac{8}{34}\cdot\frac{6}{33}\cdot\frac{4}{32}\cdot\frac{2}{31}$. The thinking: select one pair of desks in the front row. There are 4 students who can sit in either of two seats, so 8 ways. Then 3 students remain, so the next pair of desks have 6 ways to place a remaining student, then 4 ways and finally 2 ways. The denominator would be $34\cdot33\cdot32\cdot31$, which represents the ways to randomly place the four students in the 34 desks.

Right now, I'm questioning this answer. Can anyone either verify this thinking or point out my error?

Comment: Seems correct to me. What's your doubt?

Comment: I think you reasoning is correct. I don't quite understand why phrase "pairs of desks"  is used. Could we just say "8 front desks"? It could be important if desks are indeed paired, so it's possible for them to sit at different desks but still be next to each other.

Comment: It's the issue to unknowingly using an implied order. For instance, let's focus on the students, rather than the seats. Choose Al, who can be placed in any of the eight front seats. But I could have selected any of the four students, so for the initial choice there are $4\cdot8$ ways to place the first student, then $3\cdot6$ ways to place the second, and so on. This can be expressed as $4!\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4\cdot2$, which is 24 greater than the first approach. I think that I'm overthinking here...

Comment: Having first placed Al in the front left, and so on until placing Dale in the front right is going to be equivalent to having placed Dale in the front right and so on until placing Al in the front left.  The order in which we select students to choose a seat for is not particularly relevant.  You could make it relevant if you so choose, but if you do then this should also be made relevant for the denominator as well... you'll have an extra $4!$ both in the numerator and in the denominator which will cancel each other out.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you...I can believe your argument. I knew that I was overthinking the answer...